# What does the below code segment mean in typescript?

Tags: typescript, typescript-decorator

I saw below code segment in the declaration file of reflect-metadata library. Does it mean the function metadata should return an object with 2 functions? Please help explain the usage of this and share a sample of how to use it. Thanks.

```js
function metadata(metadataKey: any, metadataValue: any): {
            (target: Function): void;
            (target: Object, propertyKey: string | symbol): void;
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function is declared to return two function signatures – this is due to function overloading.

When you call `metadata` with the two args, you will be able to call the returned 1 of 2 ways:

By `(target: Function)`

```
x.metadata(1, 1)(function() {});
```

Or `(target: Object, propertyKey: string | symbol)`

```
x.metadata(1, 1)({}, '')
```

The two function signatures allow you to call a single implementation with some differing arguments.